# Problems of multiple threads sharing/accessing the same data

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have been researching into when data is being accessed or shared by multiple threads within Java. And looking into the problems such as:

- Thread Interference
- Memory Consistency
- Deadlock
- Starvation

From this, solutions to solve these problems.

So far all I seem find to fixing these problems is by using a synchronizing method.
Are there other alternatives to using a synchronizing method?
I have found most of this information from the sun Java tutorial. 
Any recommendations on further reading?

Comment: Off topic for stackoverflow. Please read the FAQ. Perhaps programmers stack exchange is where you want to post this.

Answer (score 3):

Try to keep your data read-only (immutable) if possible or copy them to have it thread-local as a general advice.

In Java there are several special non-blocking implementations of counters (`AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`, etc.) and Collections (`java.util.concurrent.*`) to use if you need to avoid synchronization for your data.

I can recommend the book "Effective Java" (Joshua Bloch) or "Java concurrency in practice".

Comment: If you could only get one of the books above - whats better? Effective Java or Java concurrency in practice?

Comment: _Effective Java_ is a **general** book on how to write good and maintainable code. It also helps to avoid several pitfalls in java.
_Java concurrency in practice_ is specialized on concurrency and for in-depth study of that topic.
I would suggest to just go to a local bookstore and look for yourself which one fits your needs. Alternatively you can look at the index of the books to have an overview of the topics: [JCIP](http://jcip.net/contents.html), [EJ](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/toc.html)